# How to click on a javascript/AJAX based element with onclick attribute using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, onclick, css-selectors

I'm trying to click a link in a dropdown menu in Selenium.

I'm accessing the element like so:

`link = menu.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Mark as shipped")]')`

The link's href is `javascript.void(0)`, and contains an `onclick` attribute which contains:

```
'com.ebay.app.myebay2.lineaction.service.LineActionAjax.processTransRequest("http://payments.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?OrderAction&transId=#TID#&action=4&pagetype=1883&ssPageName=STRK:MESO:SHP&itemid=_Item_Id", "_Item_Id", "987349587", "MarkShipped", "98739873", "_Item_Id_9874987_ss", 24")'
```

I've tried triggering this with:

```
click()
```

and

```
driver.execute_script(link.get_attribute('onclick'))
```

Also an ActionChain mousing over the link and clicking it.

But none seem to work. How do I trigger this?

Comment: can you provide us more information about what you mean when you say "none seem to work"?  do you get exceptions?  do you have some indication that the action did not happen?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Answer (score 0):

The element is a [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp) element, so ideally to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Mark as shipped"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[onclick*='MarkShipped']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@onclick, 'MarkShipped') and contains(., 'Mark as shipped')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```