# Selenium - wait until element is present, visible and interactable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I have a Selenium script (Python) that clicks a reply button to make the class *anonemail* appear. The time it takes for the class anonemail to appear varies. Because of that I have to use sleep until the element has appeared.

I want to wait until the class has appeared instead of using sleep. I have heard about wait commands, but I don't know how to use them.

This is what I have thus far:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".reply-button").click()
sleep(5)
email=browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".anonemail").get_attribute("value")
```

Comment: Do any of the answers address waiting for the element to be interactable? It can be present and clickable and still not ready for you to send keys to it.

Comment: Try: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaPtT.png

Comment: anonemail = anonymous + email. Aren't there naming conventions for class names?

Answer (score 176):

As per the best practices:

- If your use case is to validate the **presence** of any element, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) setting the [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as [`presence_of_element_located()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) which is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible. So the effective line of code will be:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".reply-button"))).click()
  ```
- If your use case is to **extract any attribute** of any element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) setting the [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as [`visibility_of_element_located(locator)`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) which is an expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed, but it also has a height and width that is greater than 0. So in your use case, effectively the line of code will be:

  ```
  email = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css"))).get_attribute("value")
  ```
- If your use case is to invoke **`click()`** on any element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) setting the [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) which is an expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it. So in your use case, effectively the line of code will be:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".reply-button"))).click()
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of detailed discussion in:

- [WebDriverWait not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808)
- [Selenium: Check for the presence of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50610553/selenium-check-for-the-presence-of-element/50621712#50621712)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This doesn't show element not found error. However, it immediately closes the browser window even if an explicit wait exists. Do you know why?

Answer (score 57):

After clicking the *Reply* button, use `.visibility_of_element_located` like below:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".reply-button").click()

# Wait for initialize, in seconds
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

email = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.anonemail'))).get_attribute("value")
print(email)
```

Following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

[Waits documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Answer (score 17):

You can use waits. Check for more information in *[Selenium waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)*.

In the example below we are waiting 10 seconds for the element to be visible, using the function *visibility_of_element_located*.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement"))
    )
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 12):

- `WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".reply-button")))`:

  - *Hey driver, wait (0-5 seconds), when you see `.reply-button` is **presence**, return that button to me!*

    - ***presence*** is present on the DOM. Hidden element is good enough.
- `WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(         EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".reply-button”))))`:

  - *Hey driver, wait (0-5 seconds), when you see `.reply-button` is **visibility**, return that button to me!*

    - ***visibility*** is present and visible on the DOM. Hidden element is **not** good enough!
- `WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(         EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".reply-button”))))`:

  - *Hey driver, wait (0-5 seconds), when you see `.reply-button` is **clickable**, return that button to me!*

    - ***clickable*** is present and visible and clickable on the DOM. Hidden element or non-clickable is **not** good enough!

[image: Other available conditions]

Comment: I really like finding this kind of answers in SO: I think they help you learn fishing instead of only giving you a fish. Kudos!

Answer (score 8):

You can use [implicitly_wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#implicit-waits):

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
driver.get("http://url")
driver.find_element_by_id("id_of_element").click()
```

It waits until element is loaded.

In your case the implementation would be,

```
browser.implicitly_wait(10)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".reply-button").click()
email = browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".anonemail").get_attribute("value")
```

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar problem to yours. I tried using `implicit_wait()` and `WebDriverWait`, but they did not work.

So I solved setting the `implicit_wait(10)` in the `web driver` instance and using this snippet to click on the button:

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[contains(string(), 'Log In')]")[0]
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern Python Selenium frameworks have smart-waiting already included before performing actions such as clicking. For example, here's a [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) script that tests a demo e-commerce website:

```py
from seleniumbase import SB

with SB() as sb:
    sb.open("https://www.saucedemo.com/")
    sb.type("input#user-name", "standard_user")
    sb.type("input#password", "secret_sauce")
    sb.click("input#login-button")
    sb.click('button[id="add-to-cart-test.allthethings()-t-shirt-(red)"]')
    sb.click("div#shopping_cart_container a")
    sb.click("button#checkout")
    sb.type("input#first-name", "SeleniumBase")
    sb.type("input#last-name", "Rocks")
    sb.type("input#postal-code", "01720")
    sb.click("input#continue")
    sb.click("button#finish")
    sb.assert_exact_text("Thank you for your order!", "h2")
```

In addition, there are simple methods for waiting for certain things if you still want to use those. Eg:

```py
sb.wait_for_element_present(selector)
sb.wait_for_element_visible(selector)
sb.wait_for_element_clickable(selector)
```

(The `selector` is auto-detected, which means you no longer have to specify CSS vs XPath.)

---

The Selenium "best practices" now recommend using frameworks that include smart-waiting for you:

That means NOT USING a long line like this anymore:

`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button"))).click()`

and instead, DO USE a framework where you can do something like this:

`sb.click("button")`

It's much cleaner, just as reliable, and displays better error messages if the element you're looking for never shows up within the default timeout.

Frameworks, such as [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), are listed on the Selenium Ecosystem page: https://www.selenium.dev/ecosystem/#frameworks